# ios NSLayoutConstraint activate is not applied immediately inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have two `IBOutlet` collections, where one list contains the constraints what has padding values set to them, and the other where all values are set to 0. In the Interface Builder, the first set of constraints is installed and the second set is not installed.

Based on the content retrieved from the server, the constraints are either kept as they are or the first set is deactivated and the second set activated.

Now this usually works okay, but I've found that there are times when the activation is not applied immediately, especially inside a `UICollectionViewCell` instance.

When the cells are first loaded, the changes are not applied, but when I scroll to some other cells and come back, the changes are applied.

Is there any documentation on this inconsistent behavior?

The following is the code activating/deactivating constraints:

```
textConstSet.forEach { $0.isActive = false }
imageConstSet.forEach { $0.isActive = true }
```

The console output after this code is run:

```
(lldb) po cell.imageConstSet
▿ Optional<Array<NSLayoutConstraint>>
  ▿ some : 4 elements
    - 0 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000223f890 V:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7f8ada588f30]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f8ada588d50 )>
    - 1 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000223f8e0 V:[UIStackView:0x7f8ada588f30]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f8ada588d50 )>
    - 2 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000223f930 H:[UIStackView:0x7f8ada588f30]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f8ada588d50 )>
    - 3 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000223f980 UIView:0x7f8ada588760.width == 0   (active)>

(lldb) po cell.textConstSet
▿ Optional<Array<NSLayoutConstraint>>
  ▿ some : 4 elements
    - 0 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002212990 V:[UIStackView:0x7f8ada588f30]-(8)-|   (inactive, names: '|':UIView:0x7f8ada588d50 )>
    - 1 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022129e0 V:|-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7f8ada588f30]   (inactive, names: '|':UIView:0x7f8ada588d50 )>
    - 2 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002212a30 H:[UIStackView:0x7f8ada588f30]-(12)-|   (inactive, names: '|':UIView:0x7f8ada588d50 )>
    - 3 : <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022126c0 UIView:0x7f8ada588760.width == 12   (inactive)>
```

Also, calling `layoutIfNeeded()` doesn't do anything. It does apply changes but they are reverted when actually displayed.

Comment: Did you define your constraint iboutlets weak or strong? Weak definition of a constraint could've caused it to be nil in a run loop.

Comment: if it is nil then why app is not crashing ? @bseh

Comment: after updating constraints you may try self.collectionViewWidgets.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

Comment: @bseh They are all strong references. In fact, `IBOutlet` collections is an array of references.